# Flask on python3.3: "TypeError: AST identifier must be of type str"

Tags: python-3.x, flask, opensuse

Hey stackoverflow community,

i want to host a flask application on an old machine, where i don't have root access. The installed python version is python3.3. The OS is openSUSE 13.1. I have installed all the needed dependencies for my local user for example with

```
pip install flask --user
```

The problem is, that i always get the following error message:

```
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 27 2014, 17:16:46) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> Flask("A")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/srv/MrR/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 541, in __init__
    view_func=self.send_static_file)
  File "/srv/MrR/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 64, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/MrR/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1046, in add_url_rule
    self.url_map.add(rule)
  File "/srv/MrR/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1401, in add
    rule.bind(self)
  File "/srv/MrR/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 730, in bind
    self.compile()
  File "/srv/MrR/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 794, in compile
    self._build = self._compile_builder(False).__get__(self, None)
  File "/srv/MrR/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 964, in _compile_builder
    code = compile(module, "<werkzeug routing>", "exec")
TypeError: AST identifier must be of type str
```

I found no helpful comment google or anything else. Flask should also be compatible with this version of python. Have you an idea, what the cause of the error might be?

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem in python 3.3. As solution i used `Werkzeub=0.14` `MarkupSafe=0.23` and `Flask=1.0.4`

My pip freeze:

```
click (7.1.2)
Flask (1.0.4)
itsdangerous (1.1.0)
Jinja2 (2.11.2)
Markupsafe (0.23)
Werkzeug (0.14)
```